# Node.js Последовательные взаимозависимые запросы mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js

Проблема с Node.js и MySQL
Появилась необходимость связать несколько запросов, причем последующие будут зависеть от результатов предыдущих.
Как пример взял обычные 2 запроса на селект, не могу связать. Первый запрос срабатывает, а на второй валит ошибку

> Error2 Cannot enqueue Query after invoking quit.

Подскажите в чем завтык, почему не хочет вызывать второй вложенный запрос?

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'root',
    password : '',
    database : 'test'
});
connection.query('SELECT * from testtable', function(err, rows, fields) {
  if (!err){
    console.log('Первый запрос: '+rows);
    connection.query('SELECT * from secondtable', function(err2, rows2, fields2) {
      if (!err2){
        console.log('Второй запрос: '+rows2);
      }else{
        console.log('Error2 '+err2);
      }
    });
  }else{
    console.log('Error1 '+err2);
  }
});
```

Comment: какая библиотека используется для mysql?

Comment: npm install mysql  под винду

Comment: Попробуйте что-то типа Async.js, думаю это решит все ваши проблемы

Comment: async.js в данном случае только позволить чуть более удобно обернуть вызовы.
Проверьте, что в коде нигде не вызывается `connection.end()`. Он может стоять, к примеру, после закрывающей скобки от первого connection.query.

Comment: Попробуйте завернуть connection в функцию, у вас следующее соединение запускается до того как завершилось предыдущее

Comment: @NumminorihSF Огромное спасибо! Действительно в этом была проблема!

Comment: @NumminorihSF а когда лучше закрывать соединение? и нужно ли вообще его закрывать?

Comment: closeConnection(connection); попробуйте, закрывать нужно в любом случае

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо было удалить `connection.end()` после первого `connection.query()`.

Если это сервер, который крутиться "вечно" то самый простой вариант - держать коннект постоянно. Более сложное, но правильное решение - использовать пул подключений, который будут закрываться сами при простое.

Ну и если подключение нужно редко - лучше сделать открытие соединения по необходимости, выполнение запросов, а после выполнения всех - закрыть.

Если взять Ваш случай (2 запроса), считаем, что их нужно один раз выполнить и забыть - я бы написал как-то так:

```js
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: '',
  database: 'test'
});


connection.query('SELECT * from testtable', function(err, rows, fields) {
  if (err) {
    console.error('Error1', err);
    return connection.end(); //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
  }
  console.log('Первый запрос:', rows);
  connection.query('SELECT * from secondtable', function(err, rows2, fields2) {
    connection.end(); //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    if (!err) {
      return console.error('Error2', err);
    }
    console.log('Второй запрос: ' + rows2);
  });

});
```

**Но** куда конкретно вставить закрытие соединения - лучше нормально продумать.

П.С. Возможно Вы плохо знакомы с асинхронностью в node.js. Если так - почитайте на эту тему.